# Angular make entire Handsontable readonly in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

I would like to make my Handsontable completely readonly, I have found some solutions on how to make it readonly via a controller but I would like to do the same in the HTML only. So no javascript changes.

```
<hot-table id="demoTable"
           colHeaders="true"
           datarows="gridData"
           settings="gridPreferences"
           height="300">

    <!-- BasicData -->
    <hot-column data="row_id" title="'ID'" type="'text'"></hot-column>
```

Here is an example column in the table, is it possible to make it readonly right here?

Comment: Add `read-only` to the `hot-column` elements?

Comment: oh yes thanks, working

Comment: @Ankh I think you can post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make individual `hot-column`s read only by adding the attribute `read-only`

```
<hot-column data="row_id" title="'ID'" type="'text'" read-only></hot-column>
---------------------------------------------------------^
```

The attribute isn't documented well but example usage can be found in the [plugin's README](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable#usage).